# Can postgres role name be `user`?

Tags: postgresql

My username in the personal laptop is `user`. So running `psql` from command line throws an error `psql: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist`. This is because the `user` is a reserved keyword(not sure about the right term) in `postgres`. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Trying to create a role `user` errors out for the same reason.

```
postgres=# CREATE USER user;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: CREATE USER user;
                ^
```

Comment: did you try CREATE USER "user" ?  (or single quotes if that doesn't work)

Comment: You're right using double quotes works.

Comment: But rather avoid reserved words as names. Very error prone.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote reserved words.  Try `CREATE USER "user"`